# PHP how to extract 3 results

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make a contest on one of my sites, I am a newbie in PHP so I am asking for your help.

I have this code so far

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("database",$con);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE source = 0";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $userid = $row->user_id;
        $points = $row->votes * $row->rating * $row->views;
        echo "UID: $row->user_id POINTS: $points <br />";
    }
```

Can somebody tell me please how can I echo just 3 results, the ones with highest values of `$points`, in descending order?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use mysqli or PDO instead of the deprecated mysql extension.

Comment: @Wrikken play nice. Everyone starts somewhere. Your tone is not constructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *, score = v.votes * v.ratings * v.views 
FROM videos AS v 
WHERE source = 0 
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Zi buna!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE source = 0 ORDER BY votes*rating*views DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Mind, that this is a performance killer: It will calculate the points for ALL videos, including those not displayed. You might want to consider a seperate column, maybe with a trigger to fill it.

I personally consider this to be good style - it helps, if you ever try to change the points algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, i dont mind about performance because the page where this script will be installed will not have so much views and i have a strong server

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1
 UNION
 SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name2
   IS was only show you 1 off all element inside table.